# Rank 2 vector bundle with trivial first chern class is self-dual

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I saw a statement used in the paper that E of rank 2 with $c_1(E) = 0$ is self-dual. I was wondering, how does one prove this statement? If it makes a difference, let the underlying variety be algebraic and rationally connected.

I thought of taking a sufficiently ample bundle bundle, to take a map $E \to L$ which would then give an exact sequence
$$
0 \to L^* \to E \to L \to 0
$$
To dualize it and to compare the classes in $Ext^1$, but I couldn't find anything on dualizing extensions.

Comment: This is true only if $c_1(E)$ is taken in the Chow group, that is in the Picard group. Then $\det(E)$ is trivial, and the isomorphism $\wedge^2E\overset{\sim}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{O}$ defines a non-degenerate skew-symmetric form on $E$, hence an isomorphism $E\overset{\sim}{\rightarrow}E^*$.

Comment: @abx I do not know much algebraic geometry.. only recently I started reading about characteristic classes... Does the same holds in differential geometry set up? I can ask a separate question but if it is too trivial it would be of no interest to users here...

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: Yes, the same argument works in differential geometry; the point is that  $c_1(E)=0$ implies that the line bundle $\det(E)$ is trivial.

Comment: @abx sorry for second question. I am reading characteristic classes from Kobayashi and Nomizu's  Foundations of Differential geometry.. I could not find that result.. Can you give a reference. Thanks.

Comment: A reference to what? That complex line bundles are classified by $c_1$?

Comment: I do not know what I was thinking at that time when I asked for more information...  We have vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$ with $c_1(E)=0$... As first chern class of $E\rightarrow X$ is first chern class of $\text{det}(E)$, we see that $c_1(\text{det}(E))=0$.. As complex line bundles are identified with $c_1$... a line bundle having trivial $c_1$ has to be trivial.. In particular, $\text{det}(E)$ is trivial.. This says $E$ is same as its dual.. @abx Is this correct?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87320/discussion-between-praphulla-koushik-and-abx).

Answer (score 2):

For a rank 2 vector bundle you can show that $E^* \cong E \otimes \mathcal{O}(-\det(E))$ (exercise!), and that $\mathcal{O}(c_1(E)) = \det(E)$, which gives the result.